# How to run an ASP.NET application with verbose debug messages of the ASP.NET runtime

Tags: asp.net, debugging, verbosity

How do I configure an ASP.NET application to write **verbose** log messages of what ASP.NET engine itself is doing? What I get with

```
<trace enabled="true" 
       pageOutput="false"
       requestLimit="10000"
       writeToDiagnosticsTrace="true"/>
```

is just

```
[2488] aspx.page: Begin PreInit 
[2488] aspx.page: End PreInit
[2488] aspx.page: Begin Init  
[2488] Unhandled Execution Error:  -- Object reference not set to an instance of an object.:
    at ...
    ...
[2488] aspx.page: Begin PreInit
[2488] aspx.page: End PreInit  
[2488] aspx.page: Begin Init
[2488] aspx.page: End Init  
[2488] aspx.page: Begin InitComplete  
[2488] aspx.page: End InitComplete  
[2488] aspx.page: Begin PreLoad  
[2488] aspx.page: End PreLoad  
[2488] aspx.page: Begin Load
[2488] aspx.page: End Load  
[2488] aspx.page: Begin LoadComplete  
[2488] aspx.page: End LoadComplete 
[2488] aspx.page: Begin PreRender  
[2488] aspx.page: End PreRender  
[2488] aspx.page: Begin PreRenderComplete 
[2488] aspx.page: End PreRenderComplete  
[2488] aspx.page: Begin SaveState  
[2488] aspx.page: End SaveState 
[2488] aspx.page: Begin SaveStateComplete 
[2488] aspx.page: End SaveStateComplete  
[2488] aspx.page: Begin Render  
[2488] aspx.page: End Render
```

Is there a way to get more verbosity?
What's about the verbosity level of application_folder/logs/ files?

Answer (score 2):

[ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) gives you a lot of detail and is very easy to add to your asp.net application

Comment: Thanks! May be useful. Though it doesn't look like it will increase the verbosity of the ASP.NET framework itself.